# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Laravel 5.4 with cors package

Tags: php, laravel, cors, vuejs2, laravel-5.4

Hi I was following this tutorial regarding Laravel and VueJs communication. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hOMkFMxY90&list=PL3ZhWMazGi9IommUd5zQmjyNeF7s1sP7Y&index=8

I have done exactly like it was said in the tutorial. It uses a CORS package https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors/

I have added the service provider middlewares everything as it was told in the tutorial but it just doesnt seem to work.
I have tried it in **Laravel 5.4 and Laravel 5.3** as well.

This is my **RouetServiceProvider**:

```
            namespace App\Providers;

            use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
            use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

            class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
            {
            /**
            * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
            *
            * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
            *
            * @var string
            */
            protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

            /**
            * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
            *
            * @return void
            */
            public function boot()
            {
            //

            parent::boot();
            }

            /**
            * Define the routes for the application.
            *
            * @return void
            */
            public function map()
            {
            $this->mapApiRoutes();

            $this->mapWebRoutes();

            //
            }

            /**
            * Define the "web" routes for the application.
            *
            * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
            *
            * @return void
            */
            protected function mapWebRoutes()
            {
            Route::group([
            'middleware' => 'web',
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
            ], function ($router) {
            require base_path('routes/web.php');
            });
            }

            /**
            * Define the "api" routes for the application.
            *
            * These routes are typically stateless.
            *
            * @return void
            */
            protected function mapApiRoutes()
            {
            Route::group([
            'middleware' => ['api' , 'cors'],
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
            'prefix' => 'api',
            ], function ($router) {
            require base_path('routes/api.php');
            });
            }
            }
```

This is my middleware code in kernel

```
 protected $middleware = [
    \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];
```

I have added its service provider too.
I have seen all the solutions here on stackoverflow but none of them seems to work. **I do not need theoretical answer but a practical solution 
Thanks**

Comment: I do not need theoretical answer but a practical solution Thanks........so a copy/paste solution will do? but an explanation for problem won't ?

Comment: i am not saying that i dont want an explanation. all i am saying is all these answers on stackoverflow will just try to explain why it happens . they dont provide a proper solution for laravel

Comment: Are you running the Barryvdh\Cors provided ServiceProvider  as well? Also, when you say doesn't work, is there any specific error or is it the general "The browser blocked the request because the remote server does not allow CORS requests?"

Comment: the error that i have posted in heading.. that is what i am getting